# Bot crashing with error: invalid bitfield or flag

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to make my bot say this when the person doesnt have permission to delete messages:

```js
else if (!msg.member.hasPermission('DELETE_MESSAGES')) {
 const number1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Invalid permissions')
  .setDescription('`❌`You dont have permission to delete messages.');
 msg.channel.send(number1);
}
```

When I try to start the bot with this, it gives this error:

> invalid bitfield or flag

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3490) states, this happens when an invalid Permission is passed to the library. Your string is invalid: The Permission is actually called `MANAGE_MESSAGES` and not `DELETE_MESSAGES`, changing the string should resolve the issue.

EDIT: There's a PR fixing this Issue which is already merged on the dev branch, I think it will be published soon to npm.

Comment: As an addendum: Here is a link to the docs where you can see what the accepted FLAGS are: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS